# Flexible array of structure in a structure in C

Tags: c

As written in the title, i might have a problem with flexible array in structure.
I am simply trying to move a pointeur from a const menu to an other. I want to extract some data from the current menu and send them out:

```
    static void DoMainMenuAction(void);

    /* Type */
    typedef enum _LCD_ItemType
    {
        E_LCD_ITEM_TYPE_BOOL,
        E_LCD_ITEM_TYPE_EXPANDABLE,
        E_LCD_ITEM_TYPE_ACTION      
    }e_LCD_ItemType;

    /* Menu Item */
    typedef struct _LCD_MenuItem
    {
        char*           Name;
        e_LCD_ItemType  Type;
    }s_LCD_MenuItem;

    /* Menu structure */
    typedef struct _NAV_Menu
    {
        const char*             Header;     /* Title */
        const uint8_t           NbItems;    /* Number of choices in the menu */
        void (*callbackFnct)(void);         /* Selected item function */
        const s_LCD_MenuItem*   Items[];    /* Menu array of Items */
    } s_NAV_Menu; 

    /* Main Menu */
    static const s_LCD_MenuItem NAV_MainMenuItems[] = {
        { "<< Back",            E_LCD_ITEM_TYPE_ACTION      },
        { "General Settings",   E_LCD_ITEM_TYPE_EXPANDABLE  },
        { "About",              E_LCD_ITEM_TYPE_ACTION      }
    };
    static const s_NAV_Menu NAV_MainMenu = {
       "Menu",
        3,
        &DoMainMenuAction,
        (s_LCD_MenuItem*)&NAV_MainMenuItems
    };

    /* Pointer of current menu */
    static s_NAV_Menu* pCurrentMenu;

    static void NAV_LcdDisplay()
    {    
        uint8_t indexItem = 0;

        /* Move to the Main Menu */             
        pCurrentMenu = (s_NAV_Menu*)&NAV_MainMenu;

        s_LCD_MenuItem NAV_LCD_MenuItems[pCurrentMenu->NbItems];

        for ( indexItem = 0; indexItem < pCurrentMenu->NbItems; indexItem++ )
        {
            NAV_LCD_MenuItems[indexItem].Name = pCurrentMenu->Items[indexItem]->Name;
            NAV_LCD_MenuItems[indexItem].Type = pCurrentMenu->Items[indexItem]->Type;       
        }

        LCD_Send(NAV_LCD_MenuItems);
    }
```

My problem appears during the second iteration of the FOR loop:

First loop, i obtain:
[1st iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sewsh.png)

At second iteration, when i try to read Items Name, i jump to the Dummy Handler.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Where is your `pCurrentMenu;` pointing?

Comment: And where/how do you allocate memory. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, my bad, edited

Comment: `NAV_MainMenuItems` is not an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* Menu structure */
typedef struct _NAV_Menu
{
    const char*             Header;     /* Title */
    const uint8_t           NbItems;    /* Number of choices in the menu */
    void (*callbackFnct)(void);         /* Selected item function */
    const s_LCD_MenuItem*   Items[];    /* Menu array of Items */
} s_NAV_Menu;
```

`Items` is array of pointers of type `s_LCD_MenuItem`.

Maybe you wanted pointer to array of type `s_LCD_MenuItem`.

```
typedef struct _NAV_Menu
{
    const char*             Header;     /* Title */
    const uint8_t           NbItems;    /* Number of choices in the menu */
    void (*callbackFnct)(void);         /* Selected item function */
    const s_LCD_MenuItem*   Items;    /* Menu array of Items */
} s_NAV_Menu;
```